# Kafka Java consumer not consuming messages from certain partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have created a topic with 5 partition with 3 replication factor.I have two consumer application running, both belongs to different consumer group.
I have one producer which is producing the messages on this topic. Below is the screenshot of parition,leader and replicas status for the topic.min.insync.replicas is having default configuration.
[image]

Initially both consumers are consuming the messages from all the paritions but after some time messages are getting consumed only from partition 2.
If i purge the topic and create again, messages will be consumed from all the parition. 
I am facing this issue very frequently.

Comment: i feel partition 2 has more data, check the consumer position by using these commands https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag

Comment: What happened to your brokers 1, 4 and 5 (they aren't in sync) ?. It seems unlikely that you consume only partition 2 as broker 2 is leader for partitions 1, 2 and 4. Do you use key in your messages ? What do logs say ?

Comment: There is no lag for partition 2. Whereas there is a huge backlog for other partitions.I am not passing key in messages for this topic.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem, @ProblemSolver? I am also facing a similar problem!